# Traducción para "To be in the soapbox"

Tags: traducción, modismos, expresiones, solicitud-de-término

**"To be in the soapbox"** o **"To be on your soapbox"** es una expresión que hace referencia a la gente que se subía en una de esas cajas grandes de madera (que se usaban para almacenar o transportar jabón) a dar un discurso en plena calle, normalmente de carácter político.

Por ejemplo, en esta entrada de [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soapbox):

> A soapbox is a raised platform on which one stands to make an impromptu speech, often about a political subject. The term originates from the days when speakers would elevate themselves by standing on a wooden crate originally used for shipment of soap or other dry goods from a manufacturer to a retail store.
>
> The term is also used metaphorically to describe a person engaging in often flamboyant impromptu or unofficial public speaking, as in the phrases "He's on his soapbox", or "Get off your soapbox."

El último párrafo podría traducirse como

> El término se usa de forma metafórica para describir a una persona enzarzada en un llamativo discurso de carácter público, improvisado o extraoficial, con frases como **"Estás sobre tu caja de jabón"** o **"Bájate de la caja de jabón"**.

Por supuesto, esta expresión no necesita mucha explicación en los países de habla anglosajona (Se ve que en el Hyde Park de Londres todavía se guarda un rincón para este tipo de discursos, el *Speakers Corner* y desde 1872 llevan discutiendo de todo).

Sin embargo en español, decirle a alguien que está **"en su caja de jabón"** cuando está haciendo un acalorado discurso público no se entiende nada. ¿Hay alguna expresión o modismo que signifique lo mismo?

Como notas aclarativas extra, los discursos suelen ser improvisados (uno se apasiona mucho con su discurso y entonces le dice eso de "get off your soapbox!") o de carácter extraoficial (aunque sean de carácter político, serían más algo como el movimiento 15M que como un mitin programado).

Comment: Pues no caigo, pero me da que se usa el término [tribuna](http://dle.rae.es/?id=acCntFo). Aunque sería interesante encontrar una expresión más coloquial.

Comment: Como curiosidad, Google Translator traduce "soapbox" como "plataforma improvisada".

Comment: ¿Qué connotación tiene la frase? ¿Se aplica a alguien hablando vehementemente sobre un tema que no tiene tanta miga, o se ve como una acción loable en defensa de la justicia/verdad/lo que fuera? Como indiqué en la respuesta de Gorpik, para mí _subirse al púlpito_ suena a "estar dando el rollo", por lo que mostré mis dudas de si era este el contexto de la expresión inglesa.

Comment: Recuerda que la expresión viene de los que daban discursos políticos y religiosos subidos a la caja de jabón, por lo cual el orador piensa que está hablando de algo muy importante, pero algunos de la audiencia pueden estar pensando "Qué cansino. Menuda comida de tarro. De qué nos quiere convencer este ahora?" Recuerdo que una vez me la soltaron a mi porque insistí en pintar el hall del condominio donde vivíamos, y el del segundo, que no quería pintar me dijo que "estaba en mi soapbox" porque los del primero no accedían por ese hall (vamos, que por un motivo u otro a nadie le interesaba oírme).

Answer (score 7):

En España, al menos (y sospecho que en muchos otros países de América Latina también), puedes usar la palabra **púlpito**. Como sabrás, el púlpito era un pequeño puesto elevado cercano al altar de la iglesia donde se subía el sacerdote para dar un sermón durante la misa u otro oficio religioso. He oído la expresión *subirse al púlpito* para expresar que alguien se ha puesto a dar un discurso a los demás, algo muy parecido (o incluso equivalente) a la idea de la *soapbox*.

[image]

Por tanto, creo que en el ejemplo que pones podríamos usar las expresiones **ya te has subido al púlpito** o **bájate del púlpito**.

Comment: Muy buena, desde luego "púlpito" mucho mejor que "tribuna". Le da un toque eclesiástico-festivo a la expresión.

Comment: De todos modos, _subirse al púlpito_ tiene una connotación negativa que creo que no existe en la expresión original.

Comment: @fedorqui A mí me parece que la connotación es similar en ambos casos, pero puedo estar equivocado, influido por la que tiene en español la expresión que propongo.

Comment: @fedorqui I think you are right that it is not pejorative in English. I think I would say someone had got on their high horse to be pejorative. That may be old-fashioned though and/or British.

Comment: Es una respuesta muy buena. En inglés existe la expresión "preaching to the pulpit" que creo que es el equivalente a "predicar a un converso". No se me había ocurrido usar "púlpito" en lugar de "soapbox". Creo que es bastante buena.

Comment: Como expresión más peyorativa en español tenemos *montar el poyo*. La palabra *poyo*, poco usada hoy día, tiene el mismo origen etimológico y similar significado que la más actual *podio*, y la palabra *montar* en esa expresión se usa con el significado de "subirse a". Hoy día la expresión ha derivado en *montar el pollo* por confusión fonética y su significado se extiende a armar un lío o un escándalo.

Answer (score 2):

Por dar una alternativa: muchas veces cuando se traduce algo no es posible dar una traducción exacta, o que use una expresión similar. Aunque eso sería lo idóneo, cuando no es posible es mejor cambiar radicalmente el enfoque mientras la idea que se exponga sea la misma que la original.

Si yo me encontrara en una situación en la que estuviera viendo a Fulano *on his soapbox* y alguien me preguntara que dónde está, en vez de hacer énfasis precisamente en eso, en el "dónde está" (*on his soapbox*), haría hincapié en qué está haciendo, y soltaría frases como:

> Ahí está, dando un discurso.
>   Está ahí soltando su rollo.

O podría usar una expresión algo más genérica pero que podría dar una idea parecida de estar haciendo algo con entusiasmo o para lo que está predispuesto:

> Ahí está, [en su salsa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X5dw8Ij#A2cgy8u).

Lo malo es que esta expresión puede servir para cualquier cosa en la que alguien haga algo con suma naturalidad, pero se puede entender que en el contexto de la situación se refiera a la persona que da el discurso.

Igualmente, para la versión negativa *get off your soapbox* procedería de la misma forma. Si fuera yo, usaría expresiones como:

> ¡Corta el rollo!
>   ¡Acaba de una vez!

O una algo más parecida pero (igual que antes) más genérica:

> ¡Baja de ahí ya!

Sé que esta respuesta es un poco [salirse por peteneras](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SpUXYQC), y por supuesto no respeta las sutilezas del original, pero no se me ocurre nada mejor que [lo del púlpito](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19503/12637), y era por dar un enfoque diferente.

Comment: +1. La verdad es que decirle a alguien "ya estás con _el discurso_" o con "el rollo" o "la cantinela" o "ya estas otra vez soltándonos _el sermón_" es otra manera de señalar que alguien está soltandote un discurso _demasiado_ apasionado.